# how to invalidateSize leaflet map in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

i'm using [vue-nav-tabs](https://cristijora.github.io/vue-tabs/#/) plugin, and using `@tab-change="handleTabChange"` event for tab changes.

**i'm using tabs in parent component**

```
methods: {
    handleTabChange() {
        this.$refs.map.invalidateSize();
    }
}
```

**this is Map(child component)**

```
methods: {
     invalidateSize() {
                this.map.invalidateSize(true);
                console.log(true)
     }
}
```

this invalidateSize method run successfully but map doesn't re render.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The tab-change event of Vue-tabs plugin is emitted synchronously with the actual operation to perform the tab navigation. Therefore most likely the new tab has not appeared yet when the event fires.

Using a short timeout after the event should give some time for the tab to appear, and invalidateSize will then be able to get the correct map container dimensions.

Comment: please log this.map()  and then test setTimeout function ... and don't forget u can use emit mounted inside child component for the parent when is ready call emit ...

Comment: @DavodAslanifakor These are much probably useful details that are worth putting as an answer on their own! :-) Just be careful as `mounted` lifecycle hook does not necessarily mean inserted into the DOM, hence not necessarily with its final dimensions.

Comment: You could also try to use the vuejs nextTick function. The best would be a fiddle with your test case, so we could try some solutions on your code.